# Read excel file byte array

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

`byte[] test = getByteArry(excelfikepath)`

I have one method where it returns the `bytearray` of the excel `.xlsx` file. To read this file i need to write these byte array using `FileOutputStream` on one server and from there i am calling another method which will read and process that excel from the server.

There is some limitation because of which i cant read excel file directly i have to put it onto another server and process.

Just wanted to know is there any way by which i can make use of this byte array and read excel file IN MEMORY instead of writing it on server.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand waht you're asking, especially since the "questions" title seems a little misleading or nondescript. If you want to read the file in memory why not feed the path or byte array to poi directly, e.g. via a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)?

Comment: I have the File at A location but i cant feed that path directly and read/process the file. so what i am doing is that i am getting bytearray of excel file from location A (step 1)  and writing it to the location B (server) and than feeding the location B path to POI and read/process the file (step 2). That is what i am doing right now. What i want is to skip Step 2 and read byteArray directly without writing it to Location B(server) ?

Comment: Well, did you try the last part of my comment?

Comment: Yes i tried it and it worked thanks ...

Answer (score -1):

This will help to get byte array out of an excel file.

```
public static byte[] getFileByteArr(String fileName) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

        try (OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(new File(fileName))) {
            try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(opcPackage)) {
                try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                    workbook.write(bos);
                    return bos.toByteArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```